# processing error SMS updating Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, sms

Wonder if you can assist me in SMS to update Data Extension syntax. I tried all kinds of options and I’m getting process errors. If I remove the AmpScript and just add a message it go to the person no problem. So I know it’s the syntax that I’m using.

```
%%[
var @response
set @response = UpdateData("DC4ME_SMS_RESPONSE", 1, "mobile", "Mobile_Number", "addeddate", SystemDateToLocalDate(now()))
]%%%%=v(@response)=%%
```

tried with just the system date and getting the same error.

```
%%[
var @response
set @response = UpsertData('DC4ME_SMS_RESPONSE', 1, 'addeddate',SystemDateToLocalDate(now()))
]%%
```

Comment: Can you add your error to your question?

Comment: ERR: There was an error processing your message

Comment: What data type is field you are trying to upsert into?

Comment: Name       Data Type
mobile      Number
response   Text
addeddate Date

Answer (score 0):

Your Mobile_Number is a literal string.  Should be a variable:

```
%%[

var @response
set @response = UpdateData("DC4ME_SMS_RESPONSE", 1, "mobile", Mobile_Number, "addeddate", SystemDateToLocalDate(now()))

]%%%%=v(@response)=%%
```

**Reference**

- [**UpdateData()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/updatedata)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I realized that after I publish this and I also changed it to UpsertData instead of UpdateData. I'm still getting the same processing error. Is there something I'm missing with some kind of setting. Do I need to enable anything in Mobile Connect in order for it to read Ampscript and Data Extension

Comment: Do it have anything to do with SUBSCRIBER RELATIONSHIP and Primary Key. What should be set for both of these is that's the case?

Comment: Why is your Mobile field a Number data type and not Phone?

Comment: Ah, you are correct. Number maxes out at 2,147,483,648. So a standard US phone number 15,551,231,234 is beyond its capacity. not sure why I selected Number. I'll test it out with Phone. Thank you sir

Comment: Changed DT to phone and it working. However, not all responses are being added to the Data Extension. Some of my testers get added some do not. Some that used to get the reply no longer get or they get the reply but nothing shows in the data extension. I've had at least 10 co-workers test for me and all I have are three records in the DE